# Java :Is Set not allowed duplicates even within List object?

Tags: java

I have a following question I have two list and i added both list in Set but it does not allow duplicate object ..Is Set check duplicates inside the object as well?

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
  {


    Set<List<String>> set = new HashSet<>();

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Hariom");
    set.add(list);
    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    list1.add("Hariom");
    set.add(list1);

    System.out.println(set.size());   
  }
```

> Printing 1

Is Set working fine it will check duplicates even inside the object?

Comment: Your real question is: are these lists equal? And I'm guessing they use content to determine that.

Comment: Your set reference should really be typed `Set<List<String>>`, otherwise you will be getting raw-type warning and it will confuse anybody who looks at your code.

Answer (score 5):

When you add a new element to a HashSet, `hashCode` and `equals` of that element are used to determine if an identical element is already in the Set. Therefore, if the two lists are equal, only one can be added to the HashSet.

Two lists are considered to be equal if they have the same number of elements and when iterating the two lists, each pair of elements are equal. Therefore your two lists are equal.

Comment: Ok If List1 contain 5 elements and List2 contain 3 elements(But these 3Element same as List1) in this case what will happen?

Comment: @subodh If the two lists have a different number of elements, they won't be equal to each other, so both will be added to the Set. Even if both lists have the same elements but in a different order, the lists won't be equal to each other.

Answer (score 1):

A set is **A collection that contains no duplicate elements**. [Check this for more](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html).
You should merge the two lists into an another if you want to keep duplicate objects.